# Rebol 3 text rendering issue using GOBs

Tags: svg, rebol, rebol3

I'm trying to better understand the Rebol 3 graphics at a lower level (i.e. not using R3-GUI). I'm having a problem rendering text in a draw gob.

**This works:**

```
REBOL []

par: make system/standard/para []

gob-svg: make gob! [ ;this GOB is just for SVG graphics
    offset: 0x0
    size: 640x480
    draw: none
]

rt: bind/only [
    size 18 para par text "This is a test!"
] import 'text

gob-svg/draw: bind compose/only [
    box 20x20 50x50 1 text 100x100 640x480 anti-aliased rt
] import 'draw 

view gob-svg
```

**This does not work:**

```
REBOL []

par: make system/standard/para []

gob-svg: make gob! [ ;this GOB is just for SVG graphics
    offset: 0x0
    size: 640x480
    draw: none
]

gob-svg/draw: bind compose/only [
    box 20x20 50x50 1 text 100x100 640x480 anti-aliased (
        bind/only compose [
            size 18 para (par) text "This is a test!"
        ] import 'text
    )
] import 'draw

view gob-svg
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't the second script be functionally equivalent to the first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyphre (Richard Smolak) answered my question over at AltMe. The summary is that I should have done a **bind/only** instead of just a **bind**. He also cleaned up my example such as eliminating an unnecessary compose. See his full response below:

*ddharing: here is working version of your code snippet:*

```
par: make system/standard/para []

gob-svg: make gob! [;this GOB is just for SVG graphics
    offset: 0x0
    size: 640x480
    draw: none
]

gob-svg/draw: bind/only compose/only [
    box 20x20 50x50 1
    text 100x100 640x480 vectorial (
        bind [
            size 18
            para par
            text "This is a test!"
        ] import 'text
    )
] import 'draw

view gob-svg
```

*For much easier preprocessing of DRAW block I suggest to use the dialect preprocessor I included into R3-GUI. See here: https://github.com/saphirion/r3-gui/blob/master/source/gfx-pre.r3.*

*This code can work independently of r3-gui as well...just execute the gfx-pre.r3 script before your actual code and then you have TO-TEXT and TO-DRAW functions awailable for your convenience.*

*The draw preprocessor is using the 'classic' DRAW dialect syntax (no need to use the command! calls directly) so your code example could then look like this:*

```
do %gfx-pre.r3

par: make system/standard/para []

gob-svg: make gob! [;this GOB is just for SVG graphics
    offset: 0x0
    size: 640x480
    draw: none
]

gob-svg/draw: to-draw [
    box 20x20 50x50
    text 100x100 640x480 vectorial [
        size 18
        para par
        "This is a test!"
    ]
] copy []

view gob-svg
```

*The reference for R3 DRAW dialect syntax can be found here: http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/view/draw.html.*